# Is the p-adic density of the image of a polynomial always rational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, limits-and-convergence, p-adic-numbers

This question was previously posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185940/is-the-p-adic-density-of-the-image-of-a-polynomial-always-rational) on MSE.

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, and let $p$ be a prime number. For $n\in\mathbb N$, let $I_n$ be the number of integers $i\in\{1,\dotsc,p^n\}$ such that there is an integer $x$ for which $P(x)\equiv i\bmod p^n$. Now define
$$\delta:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{I_n}{p^n}.$$
Remark that this limit exists since $\frac{I_n}{p^n}\geq \frac{I_{n+1}}{p^{n+1}}$ for all $n$. One could say that $\delta$ is ‘the $p$-adic density of the image of $P$’.

Now I have the following question: is $\delta$ a rational number for all polynomials $P$ and primes $p$?

This question is connected to another question [Cardinality of the image of a polynomial modulo $p^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295365/cardinality-of-the-image-of-a-polynomial-modulo-pn) on MathOverflow, which asks for general information on the behavior of $I_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Note: barring finitely many critical values, the fact that $y$ is in the image of $P$ can, by Hensel's lemma, be decided from a finite approximation of $y$. So it suffices to answer the problem in a ball around a critical value.

Comment: It could be connected to the limit of the Igusa zeta function as $s>0$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Around critical points, the density locally equals that of $f(z)=z^n$ around $z=0$, for some $n>1$ (as can be seen by letting $z$ be an appropriate power series in $x$). It should not be so hard to prove that this is rational.

Comment: I have a proof that the density is rational when $P(x)=x^n$ for some $n$. @RP_, could you give more details for your argument?

Comment: Ok I get it, when $P’(a)=0$, then the density locally equals that of $f(z)=z^n$ around $z=0$, where $n$ is the maximal integer such that $(x-a)^n$ divides $P(x)-P(a)$. But there is one obstacle left: it may occur that $a$ and $b$ are both critical points, and $P(a)=P(b)$. Then the images of $P$ around $a$ and $b$ may have nontrivial overlap.

Comment: @Riemann Sorry, I had too little time today to think about it thoroughly. But you are right, that is something that I overlooked. Perhaps it is possible to prove something more precise about what the image around a critical point looks like locally. It can't exactly be described by a set of congruence conditions, but it should be something close to that. My guess is that if you find a more precise characterization of what the image looks like locally, it should be doable to prove that the union of a finite number of such images still has rational density (again, locally).

Comment: That sounds good, I will try it out!

Comment: The strategy worked! I hope to soon submit the proof to the site.

Comment: [Edit: Corrected number for first example] As a quick sanity check, I arrive at a method and formula which e.g. tells me for $p=17$ and $P(x)=17x^2−17x$ that $\delta = 273/578$. Is that what you get, with an algorithm and/or computationally by letting $n\to \infty$? As another example, for the polynomial $P(x)=x^3−3x$ I get $\delta=1/2$ for $p=2$, $\delta=5/27$ for $p=3$, $\delta=3/5$ for $p=5$, and $\delta=9/13$ for $p=13$. Please confirm or correct.

Comment: When $p=17$ and $P(x)=17x^2-17x$, then $P(x)\equiv0\bmod p$ for all $x$. Therefore, $\delta\leq\frac{1}{17}$ which is smaller than your value.

Comment: For $P(x)=x^3-3x$ I get the same values, except for $p=3$ where I get $\delta=\frac{13}{81}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Also, the denominator should always be a power of $p$, so $\delta = 273/578$ couldn't possibly be correct.

Comment: The denominator doesn't have to always be a power of $p$. When $P(x)=x^2$ and $p=3$, we have $\delta=\frac38$.

Comment: @Riemann Oh, of course you are right. Maybe the denominator is divisible by a prime other than $p$ iff there exists a critical point in $\mathbb{Z}_p$? (Well, maybe not, because there can be cancellation of course.)

Comment: A counterexample is $P(x)=x^3+x^2$ and $p=2$; then $\delta=\frac12$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich, maybe the Igusa zeta function of the derivative $P'$ could have to do with it?

Comment: We can also define a new function: $f(s):=\int_{\mathbb Z_p}|P^{-1}(x)|^sdx$, where $Re(s)>0$. Now $\delta=\lim_{s\downarrow0}f(s)$.

Comment: Right of course, I overlooked the need to look at smaller balls around $\pm 2$ for $p=3, P(x)=x^3-3x$, now I get $\delta = 13/81$ as well. I also made several silly mistakes in the $17$ example; now I think that for $p=17$, $P(x)=x^2-x$ has density $17/36$, and consequently $17x^2-17x$ should have density $1/36$? (I am still working through your proof which looks good although it does not give out very handy formulas right now.)

Comment: I haven't worked through the entire proof thoroughly enough, but I would like a nice formula as well. In particular, it seems the proof applies to power series which seems too good to be true. I feel like I could make a sequence of polynomials with rational density which approach some power series that gives an irrational density. But I could also see why this kind of thing wouldn't happen either as some consequence of being a discrete valuation, in general I'm curious if there's any restriction on the possible rational densities we can get, or if they're always $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: @Merosity, I also thought of power series. Should I make a new question on mathoverflow for this, or modify the question here?

Comment: @Torben Schoeneberg, I think that 17/36 and 1/36 are indeed the correct values.

Comment: An even more general question: is the density rational when $P$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb Z_p$ to $\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: Ok that is not true: for $v_p(a)=0$ and $i\geq0$, define $P(p^ia):=p^{i^2}a$. Then $P$ is continuous but it’s image has irrational density (even transcendental).

Comment: For power series, doesn't it immediately follow from the case of polynomials via Weierstraß preparation? Or can there be convergence issues?

Comment: I agree with Torsten: the power series case should reduce to the polynomial case by the one-variable $p$-adic Weierstrass preparation theorem (WPT), which explains what "seems too good to be true," as Merosity wrote. Keep in mind that there are *two* versions of WPT, one for the ring $\mathbf Z_p[[x]]$ of formal power series and one for the ring $\mathbf Z_p\langle x\rangle$ of restricted power series (converging on the closed unit disc). One distinction is that the meaning of a unit differs, e.g., $1+x$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z_p[[x]]$ but is not a unit in $\mathbf Z_p\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: The WPT proves that we can write a power series as a product of a polynomial and a unit power series. But it is not immediately clear that this does generalize the polynomial case to the power series case; the image of the product of two functions may be very different from the two images of the two functions.

Comment: @Riemann you're correct. I was thinking about only the congruence $P(x) \equiv 0 \bmod p^n$ for increasing $n$ when I wrote my earlier comment, and for that kind of congruence we can replace $P(x)$ by its Weierstrass polynomial factor in $\mathbf Z_p\langle x\rangle$ since the Weierstrass unit factor will have values in $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ on all of $\mathbf Z_p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the strategies suggested by @Merosity on MSE and @Gro-Tsen and @RP_ on MO, I have  found a proof that the density is indeed always rational.

Let $P$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, and let $p$ be a prime number. If $P$ is a constant polynomial, then we obtain $\delta=0$ which is rational. So assume that $P$ is nonconstant. We shall prove that $\delta$ is rational by means of a chain of lemmas. Each lemma only uses the previous lemma.

**Lemma**

Let $g:\mathbb Z_p\rightarrow\mathbb Z_p$ be a power series
$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}g_ix^i$ with $g_i\in\mathbb Z_p$ for all $i$ and
$g_i\rightarrow0$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$. Suppose that $g'(0)=1$. Then the
restriction of $g$ to $p\mathbb Z_p$ has image $g(0)+p\mathbb Z_p$.

**Proof**

The proof is analoguous to that of Hensel's lemma.$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Now let $v\in\mathbb Z_p$ for which $P'(v)=0$, and let
$n_v\geq2$ be the largest integer such that $(x-v)^{n_v}$
divides $P(x)-P(v)$. Let $Q_v(x)\in\mathbb Z_p[x]$ be the polynomial such that $P(x)=P(v)+(x-v)^{n_v}Q_v(x-v)$. Now $Q_v(0)\neq0$.

**Lemma**
For all $v\in\mathbb Z_p$ such that $P'(v)=0$, there is an integer $N_v\in\mathbb N$ such that $$P(v+p^{N_v}\mathbb Z_p)=P(v)+p^{n_vN_v}Q_v(0)f_v(\mathbb Z_p),$$ where $f_v:\mathbb Z_p\rightarrow\mathbb Z_p$ is defined by $f_v(z):=z^{n_v}$.

**Proof**
Define the function $R:\mathbb Z_p\rightarrow\mathbb Z_p$ by $$R(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}r_ix^i:=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p^{2i}n_v^{i}\binom{\frac{1}{n_v}}{i}x^i.$$ For all $i$, we have $v_p(r_i)=v_p(p^{2i}n_v^{i}\binom{\frac{1}{n_v}}{i})\geq v_p(p^{2i})-v_p(i!)>i$, so all $r_i$ are $p$-adic numbers and $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}r_i=0$. Therefore, $R(x)$ is well-defined.\
It follows from the definition of $R$ that $R(x)^{n_v}=1+p^2n_vx$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z_p$. Now define the function $K:\mathbb Z_p\rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$ by $$K(x):=R\left(\frac{Q_v(p^2n_vQ_v(0)x)-Q_v(0)}{p^2n_vQ_v(0)}\right).$$ Then $K(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}k_ix^i$ for coefficients $k_i\in\mathbb Z_p$ with $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}k_i=0$.
It follows for all $x\in\mathbb Z_p$ that $$Q_v(0)K(x)^{n_v}=Q_v(0)\left(1+p^2n_v\frac{Q_v(p^2n_vQ_v(0)x)-Q_v(0)}{p^2n_vQ_v(0)}\right)=Q_v(p^2n_vQ_v(0)x).$$
Therefore, we see that \begin{align*}P(v+p^2n_vQ_v(0)x)&=P(v)+(p^2n_vQ_v(0)x)^{n_v}Q_v(p^2n_vQ_v(0)x)\\
            &=P(v)+(p^2n_vQ_v(0)x)^{n_v}Q_v(0)K(x)^{n_v}\\
            &=P(v)+Q_v(0)(p^2n_vQ_v(0)xK(x))^{n_v}\end{align*}
for all $x\in\mathbb Z_p$. Since $\frac{d(xK(x))}{dx}\big|_{x=0}=K(0)=R(0)=r_0=1$, we can use the previous lemma to see that the image of $xK(x)$ restricted to $p\mathbb Z_p$ is $p\mathbb Z_p$. Therefore, the image of $P$ restricted to $v+p^3n_vQ_v(0)\mathbb Z_p$ is $P(v)+Q_v(0)(p^3n_vQ_v(0))^{n_v}f_v(\mathbb Z_p)$. So the lemma holds for $N_v:=v_p(p^3n_vQ_v(0))$.
$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

**Lemma** For all $v\in\mathbb Z_p$ such that $P'(v)=0$, there is a finite set $S_v\subset\mathbb Z$ such that $$P(v+p^{N_v}\mathbb Z_p)=P(v)+p^{n_vN_v}Q_v(0)\left(\{0\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{s\in S_v}\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}p^{in_v}(s+p^{2v_p(n_v)+1}\mathbb Z_p)\right)\right).$$

**Proof**
Define $S_v:=\{a^{n_v}\mid 0<a<p^{v_p(n_v)+1},p\nmid a\}$. Then it follows from arguments similar to the proof of Hensel's lemma that for all $i\geq0$, the image of $f_v$ restricted to $p^i\mathbb Z_p\backslash p^{i+1}\mathbb Z_p$ is equal to $p^{in_v}\bigcup_{s\in S_v}(s+p^{2v_p(n_v)+1}\mathbb Z_p)$. Taking the union over all $i$, we see that the image of $f_v$ equals $\{0\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{s\in S_v}\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}p^{in_v}(s+p^{2v_p(n_v)+1}\mathbb Z_p)\right)$. Therefore, this lemma follows from the previous lemma.
$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

**Lemma**
For all $\sigma\in P(\mathbb Z_p)$, there is an integer $M_{\sigma}\geq0$ such that $$P(\mathbb Z_p)\cap(\sigma+p^{M_{\sigma}}\mathbb Z_p)$$ has rational $p$-adic density.

**Proof**
First, suppose that there is an $x\in\mathbb Z_p$ such that $P(x)=\sigma$ and $P'(x)\neq0$. Then it follows from arguments similar to Hensel's lemma that $P(\mathbb Z_p)$ contains a neighbourhood of $\sigma$. This immediately proves the lemma.\
Now suppose that for all $x\in\mathbb Z_p$ such that $P(x)=\sigma$, we have $P'(x)=0$. Let $V_{\sigma}:=P^{-1}(\sigma)$, then $V_{\sigma}$ is a finite set since $P$ is nonconstant. Since $P$ is continuous, we can choose $M_{\sigma}\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ such that $P^{-1}(\sigma+p^{M_{\sigma}}\mathbb Z_p)$ is contained in $\bigcup_{v\in V_{\sigma}}(v+p^{N_v}\mathbb Z_p)$. Now it follows that $$P(\mathbb Z_p)\cap(\sigma+p^{M_{\sigma}}\mathbb Z_p)=\bigcup_{v\in V_{\sigma}}P(v+p^{N_v}\mathbb Z_p)\cap(\sigma+p^{M_{\sigma}}\mathbb Z_p).$$
Using the previous lemma, we see that this set equals
$$\bigcup_{v\in V_{\sigma}}\left(\sigma+p^{n_vN_v}Q_v(0)\left(\{0\}\cup\left(\bigcup_{s\in S_v}\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}p^{in_v}(s+p^{2v_p(n_v)+1}\mathbb Z_p)\right)\right)\right)\cap(\sigma+p^{M_{\sigma}}\mathbb Z_p).$$
Let $n:=\mathrm{lcm}_{v\in V_{\sigma}}(n_v)$. Then there exists an integer $C>0$ and a finite collection of numbers $a_l\in \mathbb Z_p\backslash p^{C}\mathbb Z_p$, $1\leq l\leq L$, such that our set can be written as
$$P(\mathbb Z_p)\cap (\sigma+p^{M_{\sigma}}\mathbb Z_p)=
\{\sigma\}\cup\bigcup_{l=1}^{L}\left(\sigma+\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}p^{in}(a_l+p^{C}\mathbb Z_p)\right).$$
The $p$-adic density of this set is $$\lvert\{a_l\bmod p^{C}\mid 1\leq l\leq L\}\rvert\cdot \frac{p^n}{p^n-1}\cdot p^{-C}$$ which is a rational number.
$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

**Theorem**
The $p$-adic density of $P(\mathbb Z_p)$ is rational.

**Proof**
When we define $B_{\sigma}:=\sigma+p^{M_{\sigma}}\mathbb Z_p$ for all $\sigma\in P(\mathbb Z_p)$, then $\{B_{\sigma}\mid \sigma\in P(\mathbb Z_p)\}$ is an open cover of $P(\mathbb Z_p)$. Since $\mathbb Z_p$ is a compact set and $P$ is continuous, the image $P(\mathbb Z_p)$ is also a compact set. Therefore, the open cover has a finite subcover $\{B_{\sigma_1},\dots,B_{\sigma_q}\}$ which is minimal. The sets in this subcover must be pairwise disjoint, so it follows that $P(\mathbb Z_p)$ is the disjoint union of the sets $B_{\sigma_i}\cap P(\mathbb Z_p)$ for $1\leq i\leq q$. Therefore, the $p$-adic density of $P(\mathbb Z_p)$ is the sum of the densities of these sets. By the last lemma, all those densities are rational. Therefore their sum is also rational.$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$