# p-adic density of the image of a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, polynomials, p-adic-analysis

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, and let $p$ be a prime number. Recently, [a user of MO proved](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405487/342938) that the limit
$$\delta_p(P) := \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\{P(x) \bmod p^n : x = 1,\dots,p^n\}|}{p^n} $$
exists and is equal to a rational number.

Is there a reference to this result in the literature?

Thanks.

Comment: Judging by the amount of attention attracted by that MO question (and the related math.SE one), I think we can be pretty sure that nobody on this forum knows such a reference, or they would have posted it there! Let's hope that the answer posted there gets transformed into a research article soon -- then that can become an answer to this question as well.