# Cardinality of a polynomial image $\pmod{p^n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, finite-fields

Given $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ a polynomial, $n$ a positive integer and $p$ a prime, there is a result that relates $|\text{Im } P \pmod{p^n}|$ with $|\text{Im } P \pmod{p^{n+1}}|$ perhaps in terms of some divisibility?

Obs. Clearly, $\text{Im } P \pmod{n} = \{ 
m \in \mathbb{Z}_n \ :\ \exists\  x \in \mathbb{Z}_n \mid P(x)\equiv m \pmod n\}$.

The motivation of this question is just looking at the polynomial $x^k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}^*$ modulo $p^n$ and $p^{n+1}$ and noticing the divisibility
$$\#(\text{Im } P \pmod{p^n})- l_n \mid \# (\text{Im } P \pmod{p^{n+1}})- l_{n+1}$$
where
$$l_{n} = \# \{m \in ( \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}-(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}) \ :\ \exists\  x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^n} \mid P(x)\equiv m \pmod{p^{n}} \},\ $$
$$l_{n+1} = \# \{m \in ( \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n+1}}-(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1} \mathbb{Z})^{\times}) \ :\ \exists\  x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n+1}} \mid P(x)\equiv m \pmod{p^{n+1} }\}$$
given when considering $x$ written with the primitive root modulo $p^{n+1}$ and the outputs when $x \in  (\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $x \in  (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Comment: Note that this divisibility is ultimately due to Hensel's lemma, whose application here relies on the fact that $\left(x^k\right)' = kx^{k-1}$ has no invertible roots when $p \nmid k$.

Comment: That display is hard to parse, due to its being so long, having some unfortunate linebreaks, and using the same symbol for cardinality, "divides", and "such that" (I think). Maybe introduce some abbreviations first, and decrease the amount of white space in a few places.

Comment: There was a very nice MO question about this last year: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405262/is-the-p-adic-density-of-the-image-of-a-polynomial-always-rational. Maybe there might be something useful there.